# Geometric Realization with Cyclic Fundamental Group of Order $n$

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am reading through John Lee's book on topological manifolds and in the middle of attempting a question on page 274.  The question asks the reader to assume $n$ to be an integer greater than $2$ and to construct a polygonal presentation whose geometric realization has a fundamental group which is cyclic of order $n$.

Does anyone have any clues on this one?

Comment: Do you know how to do it for $n=2$?

Comment: Yes, I think so, I take it you do it for the $n = 2$ case and induct on that?

Comment: I don't think you need induction, the hint I'll give is that you can do it with a polygon that has $n$ sides. See if you can generalize the construction for $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corollary 7.3 in Bredons book "Geometry and topology" states that if a group G acts properly discontinuously on the simply connected and locally arcwise connected space X then $G = \pi_1(X/G)$ where $X/G$ is the set of orbits of all points under the group action with the topology induced by the projection map.

For an example of an application of this, look up lens spaces.